# Serving files outside the DocumentRoot with apache 2.4 and php5-fpm

Tags: php, php-fpm, apache-2.4

I'm trying to serve a php file outside my document root with apache 2.4 and php5-fpm. My virtual host looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /data/projects/domain/www

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/data/projects/domain/www/$1
    DirectoryIndex _start.php
</VirtualHost>
```

This website uses a webapp which is installed in /opt/vendor/webapp/. I already have an Alias to serve the static files of the webapp, this works perfectly.

But the css less and minified javascript files are generated on the fly by a php file. This doesn't seem to work because the php file is outside my DocumentRoot.

Is there a way to serve php files outside of your DocumentRoot with php-fpm?

Edit:
The requests to the css and javascript files that are generated on the fly are rewritten to a php file called _generator.php. The error in de apache error log is:

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22105:tid 140602507183872] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:47544] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
```

Comment: Have you tried to add another ProxyPassMatch directive with a js|css regular expression?

Comment: The requests to css/js files are rewritten to _generator.php with rewrite engine. Also, the error in the apache error log is from proxy_fcgi.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when a PHP application's code is moved outside of the DocumentRoot there is a front controller script that acts as a bootstrap to load other PHP code. It may setup include paths, load a configuration PHP file in another location--like your `...vendor/webapp` directory, and execute some logic to figure out what code to run based on the web request URI.

I see that you have a file called `_start.php` for the directory index. This looks like a front controller script; which is accessible from the web. Without more information about the code in `_start.php` or `...vendor/webapp` there's really not enough information to answer your dynamic CSS question.

Try to read the code in `...vendor/webapp` for assistance (README?) configuring it to be served. My guess is that your front controller needs to be told where to find the site code (`...vendor/webapp`).